# I cannot access the data I entered on one HTML page from another HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, json

i watched and read a few videos and documents over how can i access the data on one HTML page from another HTML page and try them but i couldn't access in any way. i used to solve this problem JSON but it couldn't help to solve it. how can i access it.

add.HTML

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" id="myForm">
        <input type="text" name="input" id="input" placeholder="input">
        <button type="submit">add</button>
    </form>
    
    <script>
       const form = document.getElementById('myForm')
       const input = document.getElementById('input')
       form.addEventListener('submit' , function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            const inputValue = input.value;
            localStorage.setItem('myInput' , inputValue)
        
       })
    </script>
</body>
```

show.HTMl

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="showInput"></p>
    <script>
        const input = localStorage.getItem('myInput')
        document.getElementById('showInput').textContent = input;
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Are these two files on the same domain? Do you use a server to serve your files or do you just double click the html file?

Comment: Any messages in the console?

Answer (score 2):

The only reason I can think which would cause this is if you are not using HTTP.

LocalStorage requires that the two documents be on the same [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin).

Your code runs fine when I spin up a local HTTP server and load them as *http://localhost:7007/a.html* and *http://localhost:7007/b.html*.

`localStorage.getItem('myInput')` returns `null` if I try to load them as *file:///path/to/a.html* and *file:///path/to/b.html* because documents on *file:* scheme URLs are always considered to be different origins (this prevents, for example, someone sending you an HTML document as an email attachment which, when you open it from *file:///tmp/dfdsfd-fdf-dfdfd.html*, runs some JS that goes digging for your personal data).

---

When doing web development you should always test using a local HTTP server. There are numerous features which are disabled or altered when working on *file:* scheme URLs.